# Kubernetes Job to create a volume snapshot

Tags: kubernetes, jobs, persistent-volumes

I have a job, which I want to run regularly in Kubernetes 1.19.3 (DigitalOcean).

For this job, I need to take a snapshot of a PVC and do stuff to it. I know how can I run a job and mount a volume to the pod it runs, but I have a hard time finding out how to take that snapshot at the beginning of this job.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Are you using the Digital Ocean block storage provider for the PV?

Comment: yes, I do [space]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool of choice to take PV snapshots in K8s is [VolumeSnapshots](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/).

The trouble with them is that they don't come  yet) with functionality for periodic triggering. So, you would have to create them from a K8s CronJob. However, doing so is not terribly straight forward, since your CronJob Pod would need to have a K8s client installed and require access to the K8s API Server with RBAC.

There are a couple of options to get there, reaching from writing your own image from scratch to using open-source solutions based on the clients from this project [k8s client libraries](https://github.com/kubernetes-client).

Seeing that dynamic K8s manifest applying is somewhat badly supported by K8s, I actually started an open source project myself, that you could use for this purpose: [K8sCrud](https://github.com/fritzduchardt/k8scrud).

Comment: thank you, I knew about the volume snapshot thing, but provisioning it on demand was the question. I found that there is a java client for k8s, so I'll use that I think

Comment: My cronjob is not able to create multiple volume snapshots with same name. What I am doing wrong?